Getting arbitrarily close to $L^1$ norm using $L^\infty$ functions and duality
Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be complex-valued with norm
$$\| f\|_{L^1} >\varepsilon$$
for some $\varepsilon >0$. We know that we can write this using duality as
$$\sup_{\| g\|_{L^\infty=1}}\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} fg\,dx\right|>\varepsilon.$$ Is it true that for any such $\varepsilon$ there exist $\varepsilon<\delta <\| f\|_{L^1}$ and $g_0$ with $\|g_0\|_{L^\infty}=1$ such that
$$\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} fg_0\,dx\right|>\delta.$$
In other words, can we get arbitrarily close to the norm using the dual class of functions?

For $f\in L^1$, you can get the norm itself: just take $g=\text{sign}(f)\in L^\infty$. Did you mean to have the roles of $1$ and $\infty$ flipped?
